# Assistance with bash functionality

Tags: bash

I need to access data from a server that is behind a proxy. Thus, I can normally ssh to the proxy and then ssh to the destination to perform administration. However, not sure how to achieve this in bash. I do have a local ssh alias that will tunnel through the proxy automatically when i "ssh destination", but this must be in my environment or something and not used by the script.

In essence, is it possible to "ssh proxy ssh destination $commmand" in bash? I have tried the this exact command and had no success.

Comment: Would it be a problem to set up an iptables rule to forward a port from 'proxy' to 'host behind proxy'? That's how I always do it.

Comment: Sorry, that's way too messy for this particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you want, but if forwarding a port is out of the question, you could set up an SSH tunnel first:

```
ssh -L 2222:hostbehindproxy:22 user@proxy
```

And then

```
ssh -p 2222@localhost user@hostbehindproxy "command"
```

You can devise something that keeps the tunnel up at all times. A very crude way:

```
while true; do
    # you need to have public key authentication for this to work on the background
    ssh -N -L 2222:hostbehindproxy:22 user@proxy
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: For keeping the connections alive, http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/ autossh FTW!

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding these lines in your ~/.ssh/config

```
Host remote_server
  HostName remote_server_url_or_ip
  User remote_user 
  ProxyCommand ssh proxy_user@proxy nc %h %p
```

Then you will be able to run only *ssh remote_server*. The ip/url and user will be the ones defined in the file. It will first ssh to *proxy* as user *proxy_user* and use nc on that session to talk to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the command you wrote, you have to manage the authentication from the proxy server to the destination server. You can create a key pair (with ssh-keygen) on the proxy server and then put the public key in the authorized_keys file of the destination server (in .ssh/ directory of the user you use).

After the key exchange, your "ssh proxy ssh destination $commmand" should work.

Comment: I tried that before my tunnel answer, and it says: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.... [MOTD] ... stdin: is not a tty`

Comment: I've made a test on my machines (CentOS) and it works!

Comment: Hm, it works when I manually ssh to both the servers. Guess I must be passing my agent. Yet I tried 'ssh -A proxy ssh destination' but had no luck. Although.. running it through bash probably doesn't give it access to the keys loaded in my chain.

Comment: Can you post the error you get?